# TCP keep-alive parameters not being honoured

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am experimenting with TCP keep alive on my Linux box, and have written the following small server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  // inet_ntop
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>          // addrinfo stuff

using namespace std;

typedef int SOCKET;

int main(int argc, char *argv []) 
{
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_IPv4;
    memset(&sockaddr_IPv4, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sockaddr_IPv4.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_IPv4.sin_port = htons(58080);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.6.186.24", &sockaddr_IPv4.sin_addr) != 1)
        return -1;

    SOCKET serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (bind(serverSock, (sockaddr*)&sockaddr_IPv4, sizeof(sockaddr_IPv4)) != 0 || listen(serverSock, SOMAXCONN) != 0) 
    { 
        cout << "Failed to setup listening socket!\n";
    }

    SOCKET clientSock = accept(serverSock, 0, 0);
    if (clientSock == -1) 
        return -1;

    // Enable keep-alive on the client socket
    const int nVal = 1;
    if (setsockopt(clientSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &nVal, sizeof(nVal)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to set keep-alive!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the keep-alive options that will be used on the client socket

    int nProbes, nTime, nInterval;
    socklen_t nOptLen = sizeof(int);
    bool bError = false;

    if (getsockopt(clientSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &nTime, &nOptLen) < 0) { bError = true; }
    nOptLen = sizeof(int);

    if (getsockopt(clientSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &nProbes, &nOptLen) < 0) {bError = true; }
    nOptLen = sizeof(int);

    if (getsockopt(clientSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &nInterval, &nOptLen) < 0) { bError = true; }

    cout << "Keep alive settings are: time: " << nTime << ", interval: " << nInterval << ", number of probes: " << nProbes << "\n";

    if (bError) 
    {
        // Failed to retrieve values
        cout << "Failed to get keep-alive options!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    int nRead = 0;
    char buf[128];
    do 
    {
        nRead = recv(clientSock, buf, 128, 0);
    } while (nRead != 0);


    return 0;
}
```

I then adjusted the system-wide TCP keep alive settings to be as follows:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
20
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
30
```

I then connected to my server from Windows, and ran a Wireshark trace to see the keep-alive packets.  The image below shows the result.

[image: Packets 1]

This confused me, since I now understand the keep-alive interval to only come into play if no ACK is received in response to the original keep alive packet (see my [other question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350802/220381)).  So I would expect the subsequent packets to be consistently sent at 20 second intervals (not 30, which is what we see), not just the first one.

I then adjusted the system wide settings as follows:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
30
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
20
```

This time when I connect, I see the following in my Wireshark trace:

[image: Packets2]

Now we see that the first keep-alive packet is sent after 30 seconds, but each one thereafter is also sent at 30 seconds, not the 20 as would be suggested by the previous run!

**Can someone please explain this inconsistent behaviour?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Roughly speaking, how it is supposed to work is that a keepalive message will be sent every `tcp_keepalive_time` seconds.  If an `ACK` is not recieved, it will then probe every `tcp_keepalive_intvl` seconds.  If an `ACK` is not received after `tcp_keepalive_probes`, the connection will be aborted.  Thus, a connection will be aborted after at most

```
    tcp_keepalive_time + tcp_keepalive_probes * tcp_keepalive_intvl
```

seconds without a response.  See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) kernel documentation.

We can easily watch this work using [netcat keepalive](https://github.com/cyberelf/netcat-keepalive), a version of netcat that allows us to set tcp keepalive parameters (The sysctl keepalive parameters are the default, but they can be overriden on a per socket basis in the [`tcp_sock`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tcp.h?v=2.6.32#L247) struct).

First start up a server listening on port `8888` with `keepalive_timer` set to 5 seconds, `keepalive_intval` set to 1 second, and `keepalive_probes` set to 4.

```
    $ ./nckl-linux -K -O 5 -I 1 -P 4 -l 8888 >/dev/null &
```

Next, let's use `iptables` to introduce loss for `ACK` packets sent to the server:

```
    $ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 \
    >   --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,RST,FIN ACK \
    >   -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 \
    >   -j DROP
```

This will cause packets that are sent to TCP port 8888 with just the `ACK` flag set to be dropped with probability 0.5.

Now let's connect and watch with the vanilla netcat (which will use the sysctl keepalive values):

```
    $ nc localhost 8888
```

Here is the capture:

[image: TCP keepalive capture]

As you can see, it waits 5 seconds after receiving an `ACK` before sending another keepalive message.   If it doesn't receive an `ACK` within 1 second, it sends another probe, and if it doesn't receive an `ACK` after 4 probes, it aborts the connection.  This is exactly how keepalive is supposed to work.

So let's try to reproduce what you were seeing.  Let's delete the iptables rule (no loss), start a new server with `tcp_keepalive_time` set to 1 second, and `tcp_keepalive_intvl` set to 5 seconds, and then connect with a client.  Here is the result:

[image: Capture with keepalive_time < keepalive_intvl, no loss]

Interestingly, we see the same behavior you did: after the first `ACK`, it waits 1 second to send a keepalive message, and thereafter every 5 seconds.

Let's add the iptables rule back in to introduce loss to see what time it actually waits to send another probe if it doesn't get an `ACK` (using `-K -O 1 -I 5 -P 4` on the server):

[image: Capture with keepalive_time < keepalive_intvl, with loss]

Again, it waits 1 second from the first `ACK` to send a keepalive message, but thereafter it waits 5 seconds whether it sees an `ACK` or not, as if `keepalive_time` and `keepalive_intvl` are both set to 5.

In order to understand this behavior, we will need to take a look at the linux kernel TCP implementation.  Let's first look at [`tcp_finish_connect`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L5567):

```
 if (sock_flag(sk, SOCK_KEEPOPEN))
        inet_csk_reset_keepalive_timer(sk, keepalive_time_when(tp));
```

When the TCP connection is established, the keepalive timer is effectively set to `tcp_keepalive_time`, which is 1 second in our case.

Next, let's take a look at how the timer is processed in [`tcp_keepalive_timer`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c#L663):

```
  elapsed = keepalive_time_elapsed(tp);

  if (elapsed >= keepalive_time_when(tp)) {
          /* If the TCP_USER_TIMEOUT option is enabled, use that
           * to determine when to timeout instead.
           */
          if ((icsk->icsk_user_timeout != 0 &&
              elapsed >= icsk->icsk_user_timeout &&
              icsk->icsk_probes_out > 0) ||
              (icsk->icsk_user_timeout == 0 &&
              icsk->icsk_probes_out >= keepalive_probes(tp))) {
                  tcp_send_active_reset(sk, GFP_ATOMIC);
                  tcp_write_err(sk);
                  goto out;
          }
          if (tcp_write_wakeup(sk, LINUX_MIB_TCPKEEPALIVE) <= 0) {
                  icsk->icsk_probes_out++;
                  elapsed = keepalive_intvl_when(tp);
          } else {
                  /* If keepalive was lost due to local congestion,
                   * try harder.
                   */
                  elapsed = TCP_RESOURCE_PROBE_INTERVAL;
          }
  } else {
          /* It is tp->rcv_tstamp + keepalive_time_when(tp) */
          elapsed = keepalive_time_when(tp) - elapsed;
  }

  sk_mem_reclaim(sk);

resched:
  inet_csk_reset_keepalive_timer (sk, elapsed);
  goto out;
```

When `keepalive_time_when` is greater than `keepalive_itvl_when` this code works as expected.  However, when it is not, you see the behavior you observed.

When the initial timer (set when the TCP connection is established) expires after 1 second, we will extend the timer until `elapsed` is greater than `keepalive_time_when`.  At that point we will send a probe, and will set the timer to `keepalive_intvl_when`, which is 5 seconds.  When this timer expires, if nothing has been received for the last 1 second (`keepalive_time_when`), we will send a probe, and then set the timer again to `keepalive_intvl_when`, and wake up in another 5 seconds, and so on.

However, if we have received something within `keepalive_time_when` when the timer expires, it will use `keepalive_time_when` to reschedule the timer for 1 second since the last time we received anything.

So, to answer your question, the linux implementation of TCP keepalive assumes that `keepalive_intvl` is less than `keepalive_time`, but nevertheless works "sensibly."

Comment: Marvellous comment, thanks so much.  I need to chat this over with my colleague on Monday so will come back after that and award your most well deserved reputation!

Comment: Thanks very much :)  For future readers, https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html offers useful insight into the `iptables` command.

Comment: @Wad Happy to help, especially someone who is bothering to look on the wire after modifying TCP sysctl values to see if it is actually doing what they hoped.  Most don't.

Comment: I was about to embark on the same quest (capturing a trace to see why the tcpKeepAlive option on the PostgreSQL JDBC driver did not work as expected) when I came across this answer.... pure gold, thank you very much.